# How to create an alert dialog just after the phone hangs up in android?

Tags: android

I need to show some alert after the user have finished his call.

I created a receiver which monitors this.Now i want to show some alert.But i am not able to show it.Maybe because the context which i am using is wrong...

This is my code....

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (null == bundle)
        return;

    String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver", phonenumber);
    Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver", bundle.toString());
    if(phonenumber.equals("10000"))
    {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Caution");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Data Usage Exceeded");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            return;
        } });
        setResultData(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code so we can correct any mistakes you made.

Comment: Hi Niek I have updated my Question....

Comment: Maybe you could check if all your code is reached by doing some logging (a System.out or something). Maybe bundle is `null`,  maybe the phonenumber doesn't equal 10000, etc. Maybe your onReceive isn't even being called.

Comment: Yes i have properly Logged and checked... Actually this setResultData(null) is called if i call 10000 which stops the call.I have added a toast which works but this alert dialog doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the code is reached like you said, apparently you forgot this line:

```
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for alert.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("Some text");
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is just that you don't call `AllertDialog.show()` method?